# Failed audit on a new post review queue for reporting plagiarism

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-queues, review-audits

The review queue presented me with what was supposed to be a [first answer by somebody posted a couple of hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18080699).  I always lookup [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035166/is-a-function-that-calls-math-random-pure) and try to wrap my head around the comments and answers before deciding what to do with a review.  This one was an obviously excellent answer among many good answers, but I found an exact copy of it among those answers and flagged it for plagiarism.

I found an obviously plagiarized answer, flagged it, and got dinged for failing an audit.  This audit process is broken. From this point forward, I will always pass this particular audit test, because I will find the answer, notice the perfect duplication, assume it's an audit and just go with whatever the crowd decided was good.

If the purpose of the audit is to train us to do this work, then this particular test needs to accept that flagging a really good "first post" from two hours ago for plagiarism of a months old answer, is an acceptable outcome. Probably one of the best results you can get, considering the extra effort required to track down original content.

While I still have all the browser windows open, is there any additional data I can collect to help zoom in on this?

Comment: @RobertColumbia, thanks, I searched for this and didn't find anything similar.  How did you find it?  So, it doesn't solve my problem and the option I am given at this point is "That solved my problem!" or "No,...I will edit to explain...".  Should I add a "me-too" to the other thread?  SO needs a proper bug/feature request tracking system. Using Meta's rules for posting isn't a very good interface for these kinds of problems.

Comment: What happens if I do click "That solved the problem"? Does this thread disappear or just get tagged as a duplicate?

Comment: It gets tagged/closed as a duplicate. The question won't disappear.

Comment: I'll edit the post, I want to know where this issue is being tracked for repair.

Comment: I'll figure it out later. Closing...